# VBA argument not optional error userfrom listbox

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I wrote the following code for a UserForm but I keep getting an `argument not optional` error.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   Select Case LCase(Me.ListBox2.Text)
   Case "Analysis": Call macro1
   Case "" 
        MsgBox "nothing selected"
   Case Else
        MsgBox Me.ListBox2.Text
   End Select
End Sub
```

macro 1 code:

```
Sub macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Analysis"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
Range("A13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year"
Range("B13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
Range("C13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[-1]+1>R9C2,"""",RC[-1]+1),"""")"
Range("C13").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C13:HS13"), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("C13:HQ13").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error? I'm guessing Macro1 needs an argument provided.

Comment: Also your select case is based on lowercase listbox2.Text. One of your case statements is "Analysis" - this will never run because it is not lowercase.

Comment: The second line is highlighted

Comment: What is the code for Macro1?

Comment: Sub macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Analysis"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
    Range("A13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year"
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("C13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[-1]+1>R9C2,"""",RC[-1]+1),"""")"
    Range("C13").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C13:HS13"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C13:HQ13").Select
End Sub

Comment: I'm not too sure about that one, sorry. All I can think of is that LCase has been redefined somewhere. The error message you're getting means you are missing an argument in a function call somewhere. All the code you've provided looks OK to me. You said the error occurs on line 2. Is that this line?: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Comment: Yes. it is the Private Sub CommandButton3_Click(). I adjusted the LCase but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks. The LCase bit fixed an error you would have encountered later. Do you know if the button is part of an array?

Comment: Listbox1 is an array then I've a button that moves selections from listbox1 to listbox2. That all works fine. Now, I want to call a macro when commandbutton3 is clicked and if  "analysis" is found in lisbox2

Answer (score 1):

First, your method of referencing the ListBox is a problem. See the code below Also, I had to add Sheet Name before Range and then this worked for me...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i as Integer
Dim sValue as String
   For i = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
       If Me.ListBox2.Selected(i) Then
           sValue = ListBox2.List(i)
       End If
   Next i

   Select Case LCase(sValue)
      Case "Analysis": Call macro1
      Case "" 
          MsgBox "nothing selected"
      Case Else
          MsgBox sValue.Text
   End Select
End Sub

Sub macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Analysis"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
Sheets("Analysis").Range("A13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year"
Sheets("Analysis").Range("B13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
Sheets("Analysis").Range("C13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[-1]+1>R9C2,"""",RC[-1]+1),"""")"
Sheets("Analysis").Range("C13").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Analysis").Range("C13:HS13"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Sheets("Analysis").Range("C13:HQ13").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "The second line is highlighted" ... why not post the actual line?

Comment: the following line is highlighted when I get the error : Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Comment: Have you tried to step thru the code one line at a time? If not, then you should. Since you have no error traps, you can be misled as to the correct source of the error.

Comment: See updated answer - your issue is with reference to listbox.